# WAMP server reporting an error: "you are not connected to a network"

Tags: wampserver

When I open my WAMP server and navigate to `localhost` I receive the following error message:

> You are not connected to a network

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The TCP Network stack must be loaded. Are you using a Laptop that is currently not connected to the internet? Somethime the laptop does not load the TPC Stack if it does not think it need it. To check this, connect to the internet and then try using WAMPServer

Comment: when I connected the Internet and  then click on localhost   then showing 'this page can't be displayed'

Comment: Ok so what are you putting in the address bar of your browser? Also is the WAMPServer icon in the system tray Green?

Comment: system tray is green.and address bar only 'localhost'